# Sort By Dates Descending Using pd.crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, crosstab

I am trying to download data from the NYC COVID website, do some cleaning, and then do a crosstab with dates as columns and the region as rows.

The problem is that when I do the crosstab. the dates are presented in ascending order from left to right where I would like to see the most recent date on the left and then get older as the columns move to the right.

I'd really appreciate some help - this has me stumped.  Thanks!

So my headers currently look like:|

| week_ending | 2020-08-08 | 2020-08-15 |
| --- | --- | --- |

And I need them to look like:|

| week_ending | 2021-02-13 | 2021-02-06 |
| --- | --- | --- |

The code follows

```
import pandas as pd

trendszipcode='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nychealth/coronavirus-data/master/trends/percentpositive-by-modzcta.csv'


trendszipcode = pd.read_csv(trendszipcode,delimiter=",", index_col="week_ending").reset_index()

df=pd.melt(trendszipcode, id_vars=['week_ending'])
df[['Toss','Region']] = df['variable'].str.split('_',expand=True)
df[['Region','week_ending','value']]
df.week_ending=pd.to_datetime(df.week_ending)
df_historical=df[['Region','week_ending','value']]
df_historical=df_historical.sort_values(by='week_ending', ascending=False)
pd.crosstab(df_historical.Region, df_historical.week_ending, values=df_historical.value, aggfunc='sum').round(2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with `ascending=False` and `axis=1` for descending sorting columns fileld by `DatetimeIndex`:

```
(pd.crosstab(df_historical.Region,df_historical.week_ending,values=df_historical.value,aggfunc='sum')
   .round(2)
   .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False))
```